# sweet alert theme is not applied in vue3

Tags: javascript, sass, vuejs3, inertiajs

so I want to style my sweet alert by changing its theme to dark theme, but it wont change when I import the `scss` and use the import of `sweetalert2.js` by the doc.
Here I'm using Laravel Inertiajs

When I'm importing like this `import Swal from "sweetalert2";` it shows the basic theme of sweetalert even though I import it on the `style` tag below

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@sweetalert2/themes/dark/dark.scss";
</style>
```

[image: normalstyle]

when I import it according to docs like this `import Swal from "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js";`
but the sweetalert is looking like this

[image: unstyled dark alert]

I assume that the laravel or the vue cant find the scss file ? how do I import it to the style to `vue component` that it can find the scss ?

[image: location of scss]

the location of the scss is inside the `node_modules/@sweetalert2/themes/dark`